# How do I mirror HTML in a github repo via gh-pages

Tags: github

I have a github project that includes a number of HTML pages that display test results and other useful info when viewed in a browser.  Instead of requiring users to checkout the data, I'd like to use github's hosted gh-pages to provide the latest version of these files from the master branch.

These HTML pages depend on JavaScript source files in the master branch via relative URLs.

Is there a way to do this without repeatedly pulling into gh-pages from master?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really, pages are only built from the gh-pages branch, so you'll have to pull into that branch no mater what.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer.  I think I'll have to write push scripts to push files around.